# Model.json file not loading properly

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow

I'm trying to deploy my custom model on a webapp. I want the user to be able to upload a picture and see the results of my model's predictions. I keep getting an model not loaded properly error. I don't know why it's not working since all the files are in the same folder.

This is my first time working with deploying tensor flow models. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload an Image</h1>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="imagefile" name="filename">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="handleSubmit(event)">
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/2.8.0/tf.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        // Global variable for model access
        let model;
    
        async function initialize() {
          try {
            model = await tf.loadLayersModel('webapp/model.json');
            console.log('Model loaded successfully.');
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error loading the model:', error);
          }
        }
    
        async function loadLabels() {
            // Fetch and parse labels file (adjust based on your format)
            const labels = await fetch("labels.txt")
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(text => text.trim().split("\n"));
            return labels;
        }

        async function handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
      
            await initialize(); // Ensure model is loaded before prediction
      
            const imageFile = document.getElementById("imagefile").files[0];
            if (!imageFile) {
              console.error("Please select an image to upload.");
              return;
            }
      
            const image = new Image();
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);
            image.onload = async () => {
              const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
              canvas.width = image.width;
              canvas.height = image.height;
              const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
              const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      
              const predictedLabel = await predictImage(imageData);
              console.log("Predicted label:", predictedLabel);
            };
          }
      

          async function predictImage(inputImageData) {
            if (!model) {
              console.error("Model is not yet loaded.");
              return;
            }
      
            const inputTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(inputImageData);
            const outputTensor = model.predict(inputTensor);
            const predictions = await outputTensor.data();
            const highestProbabilityIndex = predictions.indexOf(Math.max(...predictions));
            const labels = await loadLabels();
            const predictedLabel = labels[highestProbabilityIndex];
            return predictedLabel;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding the folder directory, however I'm still seeing the same error.
I just want my model's results to show up on the webpage.